# Can windows 10 see a drive or folder shared from a windows 7 computer

Tags: windows

Before I go on trying to make this work anymore I hope to find out first if it is even possible. I have studied this a lot.  I am using windows 10 with the 1803 update
thank you !

Comment: It should absolutely be possible.  If you are using SMB, make sure your using SMBv3, instead of SMBv1. Without specifics it’s difficult to answer this question

Comment: Are you on a LAN?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can  !
I have it that I can create users with the same name on both computers and windows 7 and 10 will see each other in a peer to peer way.

Answer (score 0):

If on the same network, it works fine. I have a Windows 7 virtual machine here and I routinely connect to it, map a drive and move files from my Windows 10 machine. Make sure the Windows 7 machine is up to date with SMBv2